# map.setview, map.fitBounds

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, leaflet

When I set function with map.xxx then browser says: "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function".
What am I doing wrong?

```
function ZoomToFeature(e) {
  var layer = e.target;
  map.fitBounds(layer.getBounds());
}

function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
  layer.on({
    mouseover: highlightFeature,
    mouseout: resetHighlight,
    click: ZoomToFeature,
  });
}
```

I using leaflet and rails. Leaflet draw layers properly.

Comment: What line is giving the error?

Comment: map.fitBounds(layer.getBounds()); if you mean this.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `var layer = e.layer`. I don't think getBounds() is a callable function on the object e.target, nor is e.target a leaflet layer.